# Drag element from a list to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to build a drag and drop letter editor.  Basically the elements will be on the left that can be dragged over, and the letter workspace will be on the right.  On the right side, they should be able to move the draggable elements wherever they want.  Once they drag an item from the left to the right, it should not remove the element from the list, but rather show the hidden div on the right.  Which would allow them to copy over the same element multiple times.

```
    jQuery( "#letter .draggable" ).draggable({ 
    grid: [ 20, 20 ],
    containment: "parent",
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        var $newPosX =  jQuery(this).offset().left - jQuery(this).parent().offset().left;
        var $newPosY =  jQuery(this).offset().top - jQuery(this).parent().offset().top;

        console.log($newPosX.toString() + ', ' + $newPosY.toString());
    }
});
```

Here's an [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JNvec/) where I've got the layout and CSS, and the initial draggable.  Just need help connecting the two.

Comment: I think you'll need to use the snap property and set an event listener which detects when an item has snapped onto the #letter area so that you can create a duplicate again on the left-hand side. I think you also need to remove the containment option. Hope it goes well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I came up with a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oumichaelm/JNvec/5/) that is on track for what you want.

You should look at this [jQuery UI droppable demo](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#shopping-cart). I copied that jQuery code in the fiddle basically from the shopping cart interaction of the droppable demo.

```
$( "#letter-elements li" ).draggable({
    appendTo: "body",
    helper: "clone",
    connectToSortable: "#letter"
});

$( "#letter" ).droppable({
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",

}).sortable({
     grid: [ 20, 10 ]        
});
```

Some things to help clean up your code, you are using a css style sheet so you should get  rid of the HTML style tags.

You use a list on the left, but your Test is a span on the right.  Think its better to stick with lists on both sides.

Your first list item labeled County seal has a hidden picture, not sure why but if you want pictures to show when they move over to the right you might want to add a class to limit the size of the picture.

Comment: Thanks!  That helps alot.  The reason it's a span on the right is because it should be movable around the "letter" element.  It's for creating mailing letters, so they can move the elements as they choose.  So the idea is that the list on the left provides the elements that can be dragged onto the right and then moved around as they choose.  I'll keep playing around with it.

Comment: You can make any html element movable with jquery, just use css to style it for the look of a letter.